# Comparing two dates that use datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a form that has two date fields. I am trying to select the dates from the two inputs and compare them with JQuery. The problem I am having is that it returns `NaN`.

I think might be because the `typeof` on the dates returns strings.

```
$('#id_date_completed').change(function() {
    date_received = $("#id_date_received").val(); 
    date_completed = $("#id_date_completed").val(); 

    var diff = date_completed - date_received;
    var days = diff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;

    console.log(days);
}
```

EDIT

My question differs from [Get difference between 2 dates in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript) as I am using bootstrap-datepicker library. Arun P Johny answer was perfect

Comment: are you using jquery ui datepicker

Comment: I know this is not an answer, but when dealing with time, `momentJS` is really invaluable

Comment: You need to convert them into Date object first.

Comment: I am using bootstrap-datepicker

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get difference between 2 dates in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is `.val()` will return a string so both `date_received` and `date_completed` are string values so subtracting them will return `NaN`.

Instead you can use the [getDate()](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/methods.html#getdate) method of the [bootstrap-datepicker](https://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/)

```js
$("#id_date_received, #id_date_completed").datepicker();

$('button').click(function() {
  var date_received = $("#id_date_received").datepicker('getDate');
  var date_completed = $("#id_date_completed").datepicker('getDate');

  var diff = date_completed - date_received;
  var days = diff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
  $('span').text(days)
})
```

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<input id="id_date_received" />
<input id="id_date_completed" />
<button>Test</button>
<span></span>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It makes sence why it wouldn't work. I have implemented this though and now getting. `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function` The datepicker still works though

Comment: @Mantis might be that you are using a different datepicker plugin... which is the plugin used.. can you share a link to its documentation

Comment: I hade referenced bootstrap-datepicker.js twice. Once i removed one it started to work. Thank you for your help